# Change arduino.local server address

Tags: arduino-yun

I have a Yun and I'm trying to change the URL I type in to access the Web UI.

I've successfully changed its hostname in `/etc/config/system`, which now lets me SSH in using the new name. However:

- Going to newname.local doesn't work (no response at all).
- Going to arduino.local pulls up the green page 'Wait a moment or click here...', after which no page is rendered.

How can I access my Yun by typing in newname.local in my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be working fine.

I just logged into my Yún and changed its name by editing that file.  I then restarted `avahi-daemon` since that is what broadcasts its name (faster to restart the daemon that reboot the whole Yún).

Browsing to the new name worked fine.

```
matt@dell:~$ ssh root@arduino.local
root@Arduino:~# vi /etc/config/system
(edit the config file)
root@Arduino:~# hostname skybridge
(manually changing the hostname so I don't have to reboot)
root@skybridge:~# /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon restart
(restart the avahi daemon)
```

Browsing to `skybridge.local` now shows me the Arduino login as it should.

As a further test I have just rebooted my Yún so it runs everything from scratch and it still works fine.

There are a number of caches involved in the system, any of which may be getting in the way.  It could be that the browser has cached incorrect or out of date information about the FQDN (*fully qualified domain name*) for the name you have given your Yún, in which case just closing and re-opening your browser may help.  It may be that the mDNS lookup system on your computer (you haven't mentioned which operating system you are using, which is a big factor) has cached old or out-dated information for the FQDN, in which case flushing that cache may help (how you do that depends on your OS), or just rebooting your computer.

Incidentally, if you are on Linux (Windows lacks these basic networking facilities along with many other basic tools), you can query the network for your Arduino Yún with the `avahi-browse` and `avahi-resolve` commands.  OS X has similar tools, but I don't know off hand what the commands are:

```
matt@dell:~$ avahi-browse _arduino._tcp
+  wlan0 IPv4 skybridge                                     _arduino._tcp        local
^CGot SIGINT, quitting.
matt@dell:~$ avahi-resolve -n skybridge.local
skybridge.local 192.168.0.252
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - I'm going to test it and get back to you.

Comment: It turned out that the method did work. For some reason it didn't respond consistently right away, but a day or so later. Thank you!

Comment: @sscirrus Probably a cache that needed to expire then.  They can be pesky sometimes...